# Comparing a file name pattern

Tags: shell, unix, grep, tar

I have a few files of type server.log."date" and data.log."date"  in tar.gz archive where date is the date of the file creation.

Now I need to retrieve files of the type server.log.* and search for a string pattern in them.

Currently I'm using the below script.

```
tar -ztf file.tar.gz | while read FILENAME
do
        if tar -zxf file.tar.gz "$FILENAME" -O | grep "string"
        then
            echo "$FILENAME contains string"
        fi
done
```

The problem is that when using the above "if" condition I'm getting the string pattern matches in both server.log.* and data.log.* files

In the "if" statement I need to add a condition such that each FILENAME is compared with the pattern server.log.* and the grep is performed on only server.log.* files

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can apply before the `if` inside the loop something like this:

```
[[ "$FILENAME" != server.log.* ]] && continue
```

Of course You could also add before the if condition

```
if [[ "$FILENAME" == server.log.* ]] && tar -zxf file.tar.gz "$FILENAME" -O | grep "string"
```

Maybe a `-q` arg could be added to grep not to write lines to the stdout.

Comment: Great thanks. Can u also suggest the logic to do the same across multiple tar.gz archives......

Have tried *.tar.gz in the script but it is not working

Comment: @Agent Smith: What about `for i in *.tar.gz; do echo $i; done`?